I want to place 3 items in the Google tables dialog box with a choice of the answer from the text
For some reason, the dialog box currently works with only one list. The rest of the lists are ignored and do not want to appear in the specified cells. I tried to solve the problem in various ways and none helped.
Code gs
function openInputDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index3').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
       .showModalDialog(html, 'Заполни форму');
}

function itemAdd(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow(["  ", form.category, form.item, form.manupub, form.details, form.quantity]);
  return true;
}

HTML file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <label for="specify the date in the format: xx.xx.xxxx">Specify the date in the format: xx.xx.xxxx</label>
      <input type="text" name="category"><br><br>

      <label for="the nickname of the conductor">The nickname of the conductor:</label>
      <input type="text" name="item"><br><br>

      <label for="choice">Сhoice:</label>
      <select id="choice" name="choice">
        <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label for="choice2">Choice2:</label>
      <select id="choice2" name="choice2">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
      </select><br><br>


      <label for="choice3">Choice3:</label>
      <select id="choice3" name="choice3">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
      </select><br><br>
      

      <input type="button" value="Finish"
        onclick="google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
            .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

I tried to rewrite the HTML, but it didn't solve the problem. I have checked many forums, but I have not found a solution to this problem. I hope for your help, because there is still a lot I don't understand in Apps script.

The problem is that the HTML form doesn't include an input element with the names manupub, details and quantity, but it has choice, choice2 and choice3.
You should update the name attribute of the select element in the HTML form of the properties names on the following line:
sheet.appendRow(["  ", form.category, form.item, form.manupub, form.details, form.quantity]);


Thank you very much! I couldn't figure out the problem for a long time, but it turned out that the problem lies in one line. Thank you very much again!
